# jQuery modular script architecture - lazy loading vs inline load

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm building a `template.htm` page that has several blocks of ajax-loaded content. Because I ran into issues, I load things `synchronously` like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'module.htm'
    })
    .done(function(r) {
        $('#moduleA').html(r);
    });
```

I do this several times, loading various different `module.htm` files. All of them have a standard html file with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and header, body, etc. Plenty of jQuery in there, too.

Some of these modules have dynamically added elements, mostly using `.append()` like this

```
$.ajax(......)
.done(function(response) {
    var item = $.parseJSON(response);
    // iterating voer the JSON and appending elements
    $('div').myPluginMethod(); // utilizing the plugin here
});
```

I utilize a plugin for a specific `$.fn.myPluginMethod`, and noticed a problem:

**the problem:**
When loading the plugin using `<script>` in the header of `module.htm` and running it on its own - outside the `template.htm`, everything works fine. In console, I can type `$.fn.myPluginMethod` and it returns the function.

But if I load the `module.htm` file into the parent `template.htm` page, it no longer works. In console, typing `$.fn.myPluginMethod` returns `undefined`.

It doesn't make sense. Firebug shows the plugin script as loaded, so why would it fail?

**my theory**
Somehow I think it's to do with my ajax-load. The `.done()` method is somehow not able to "see" the plugin's objects and so it throws the `unknown method error`. I can manually paste the plugin and then it works:

```
$.ajax(......)
.done(function(response) {
    var item = $.parseJSON(response);
    // iterating voer the JSON and appending elements
    // I can paste my raw plugin code here and it will work, but that's silly
});
```

I'm trying to understand why this ajax business is causing issues. I thought once a plugin is loaded into the DOM, all scripts, dynamic or not, will be able to "see" it's methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are loading jQuery.js again from remote files. This will overwrite the jQuery object in main page. Any plugins that were registered to the initial jQuery object will then be wiped out.

Comment: yea. I had been fiddling and came to the conclusion that I'm approaching this really not the correct way. I want to be able to view modules on their own and then just tile them into a template, but I'm not doing it right. There must be a best-practice approach to this... I just haven't discovered it yet.

Comment: set server code so it doesn't include jQuery.js when page is loaded by ajax. Can send data to server `$.ajax({ data:{ ajax:true}, url:'module.htm'....` and check for `ajax` param at server